# How to get maximum for a field based on a date and get other fields also?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I know my question is bit confusing but if I show you data it will make more sense what I am trying to achieve.

I am reading everything from one table T only.

I am reading 6 fields from that table T.

**StartKey

Name

Min

LName

MName

ID**

Top Table is data, and bottom table is what I am trying to achieve.
I need to get for each startkey get max(minutes) 

 **FORGOT TO INCLUDE `20130221`** in output.

[image]

Here is what I tried so far

```
select 
       startkey,
       name,
       min,
       lname,
       mname,
       id
from T
where startkey >= '20130118'
group by startkey,name,lname,mname,id
order by startkey
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than one entry has the max value for minutes? E.g. What if there's another entry on 20130118 with a `Min` value of 299?

Comment: @Ciarán that, I have't ran across yet, and also please ignore where clause that is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each start-key, you want to find the Max "min" value. this can be done via a nested sub-query. Then , select only where the min is equal to the max(min).
Also, if you have a situation where two records can have the same value of startkey and min, then you will need to resolve that, otherwise you will select them both.

```
select  startkey, name, min, lname, mname, id
from T T1
where min = 
 (select max(min) from T T2 where T1.startkey=T2.startkey)

order by startkey
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, easy and very simple solution.

Comment: I was wondering if you can help me bit regarding this, I found a glitch, where is another condition only get maximum where flag = 0, for startkey `20130119`  maximum is `300` but there is another field called flag that is set to `1` for this row, how can I tell it to only get max value where `flag = 0`, if I enter in where clause condition where `flag = 0`, it will totally ignore and skip `20130119` meaning no result is shown for that startkey

Comment: Are you putting the flag=0 in the inner, nested sub-query? 
If so, that sub-query will return a max of 100 for the date 20130119

Comment: it worked again thanks a lot. after `T2.startkey and  flag = 0`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but from what I get you're trying to get a specific set of data.. You can force the filters by getting only the StartKeys you need. This should work:

```
SELECT StartKey, Name, Min, Lname, Mname, ID 
FROM T 
WHERE StartKey IN ('20130118','20130119','20130120')
```

If that doesn't work, you can try this:

```
SELECT StartKey, Name, Min, Lname, Mname, ID
FROM T
WHERE Month(StartKey) >= 1
```

Assuming that StartKey is a Date field.

Comment: Hi sorry, I should've not included where clause for startkey that is just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
select startkey, name, min, lname, mname, id
  from (select startkey, name, min, lname, mname, id,
               row_number() over (partition by startkey order by min desc) rn
          from t)
 where rn = 1;
```

should do that.

eg: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59f6a0/1

note that if you have 2+ rows with the same time and you want to return them all, change `row_number` to `rank`. if you only want one of them then `row_number` is what you want (though you can add extra ordering to pick a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
  From T 
      Inner Join (Select StartKey, Max(Min) AS MaxMinutes
                    From T
                   Group By StartKey
                  ) DerrivedView
    On T.Start = DerrivedView.StartKey And
       T.Min = DerrivedView.MaxMinutes
```