# SQL help needed (oracle application express)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Given this information

Among all projects chen work on, list the name of project that has lowest budget.

```
EMPID   NAME    SALARY  DID
---------------------------
1       kevin   32000   2
2       joan    42000   1
3       brian   37000   3
4       larry   82000   5
5       harry   92000   4
6       peter   45000   2
7       peter   68000   3
8       smith   39000   4
9       chen    71000   1
10      kim     46000   5
11      smith   46000   1

PID EMPID   HOURS
-----------------
3   1       30
2   3       40
5   4       30
6   6       60
4   3       70
2   4       45
5   3       90
3   3       100
6   8       30
4   4       30
5   8       30
6   7       30
6   9       40
5   9       50
4   6       45
2   7       30
2   8       30
2   9       30
1   9       30
1   8       30
1   7       30
1   5       30
1   6       30
2   6       30

PID PNAME              BUDGET       DID
---------------------------------------
1   DB development      8000        2
2   network development 6000        2
3   Web development      5000       3
4   Wireless development 5000       1
5   security system      6000       4
6   system development   7000       1
```

This is what I've written so far:

```
select min(budget), pname
from employee e, workon w, project p
where e.empid = w.empid and p.pid = w.pid and name = 'chen'
group by pname
```

Which gives me

```
MIN(BUDGET) PNAME
--------------------------
8000        DB development
6000        security system
6000        network development
7000        system development
```

How can I select just the lowest (the minimum budget) from these values? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nest a sub-query. Or order by and fetch only the first row.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524387/how-to-get-maximum-for-a-field-based-on-a-date-and-get-other-fields-also/14524576#14524576

Comment: Please choose better question titles. All the info in "SQL help needed (oracle application express)" can be expressed better using tags [sql] [oracle] [oracle-apex]

Answer (score 1):

```
select budgets.budget, budgets.pname
from
(
    select min(budget) as budget, pname
    from employee e, workon w, project p
    where e.empid = w.empid and p.pid = w.pid and name = 'chen'
    group by pname
    order by budget asc
) budgets     
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: this give 8000 as answer, where as 6000 is the lowest budget

Comment: ok, I have added an order by clause to order it by budget ascending - which will put the lowest at the top.

Comment: I am assuming you meant to add ROW_NUMBER? It isn't your query so your where predicate will fail as posted. You also have an order by in your subquery which is not allowed. Honestly the subquery by itself should be sufficient in this case.

Comment: @SeanLange rownum is oracle's equivalent of TOP. For more info, see here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Comment: Ahh. The OP never specified which DBMS they are using and we all made our assumption. :) I would think that your subquery would produce the desired result all by itself.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Oracle's processing of `ROWNUM` is peculiar. If you don't use a sub-query it will process the `ROWNUM` filter before the sort, resulting in the top-n quasi-random rows.

Answer (score 1):

use explicit join syntax,

Here is one way using analytic function `row_number`, sequence number given  based on budget with lowest being the first.

```
with cte
as
(
select row_number() over (  order by budget asc) as rn, pname, budget
from employee e
join workon w
on e.empid = w.empid
join project p
on p.pid = w.pid and name = 'chen'
)
select pname, budget from cte where rn =1
```

Comment: This was perfect, didn't understand before but now I do. Thank you for the help